# Select2 Js not working with Laravel Livewire

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2, laravel-livewire

I am using livewire in my laravel project. Where I am using a button to generate a new tab. Like this.
[image]

Normally when I refresh the page I will found the search portion.

[image]

But after adding a new tab the search portion will be vanised. Here I am using select2 js for this search portion.

The Component code is

```
<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-xl-10">
        <div class="card">
            <form wire:submit.prevent="allocationGenerate">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 class="modal-title">Product Allocations</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label>Showroom name</label>
                        <select class="form-control" style="width: 100%;" wire:model.defer="showroom_id"
                                required>
                            <option value="" selected>Select Showroom</option>
                            @foreach($showrooms as $showroom)
                                <option value="{{ $showroom->id }}">{{ $showroom->name }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card">
                        <div class="card-header">
                            Products Stock
                        </div>

                        <div class="card-body">
                            <table class="table" id="products_table">
                                <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Product</th>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                    <th></th>
                                </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                @foreach ($orderProducts as $index => $orderProduct)
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>
                                            <div wire:ignore>
                                                <select name="orderProducts[{{$index}}][product_id]"
                                                        wire:model="orderProducts.{{$index}}.product_id"
                                                        class="form-control item" style="width: 100%">
                                                    <option value="">-- Choose product --</option>
                                                    @foreach ($allProducts as $product)
                                                        <option value="{{ $product->id }}">
                                                            {{ $product->name }} - {{ $product->attribute->name }} - {{ $product->sku }} - {{ $product->barcode }}
                                                        </option>
                                                    @endforeach
                                                </select>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <input type="number"
                                                   name="orderProducts[{{$index}}][quantity]"
                                                   class="form-control"
                                                   wire:model="orderProducts.{{$index}}.quantity" />
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <a href="#" wire:click.prevent="removeProduct({{$index}})"><button class="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></a>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>

                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-secondary"
                                            wire:click.prevent="addProduct">+ Add Another Product</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br />

                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer justify-content-between">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Allocation</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

under push js i used that script

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.item').select2();
        $('.item').on('change', function (e) {
            var data = $('.item').select2("val");
        @this.set('orderProducts.{{$index}}.product_id', data);
        });
    });
</script>
```

So how can I solve these issues? I am not good at jquery. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: I think here you can find the solution to that issue
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68851307/livewire-select2-dynamic-not-updating-public-view/68854124#68854124)

Comment: when I apply this code previous data will lose that I set.